# Not Supported Exception with xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type PageRenderer from native handle  . ---> System.MissingMethodException: No constructor found for PageRenderer::.ctor(System.IntPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership) ---> Java.Interop.JavaLocationException: Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown.

It happens when application is running and I change system font size and then push application icon again. (android project)
I have PageRenderer where I have googleMap.

Comment: The error message seems to be very clear. Could you please show the code of your PageRenderer for your googleMap?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I added public constructor with Intptr and Jniownership and added view initialization in this constructor and working perfectly